# Resize iFrame width according to screen

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I writing ASP.NET MVC website

I have video from vimeo on my page, I need it to resize according to screen.

here is code of `irame`

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/197047485?color=ffffff" id="iframe1" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0"  webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How I can do this?

Comment: add media query

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Your CSS:

```
#iframe1 {
  width: 50vw; 
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nindaclaudel/24wxmh8u/#&togetherjs=f6wcF2fjsf

Comment: Viewport width and height are not universally supported, even in modern browsers.